# Encoding Plain text email

Tags: php, email

What encoding should I use if I want to send plain text emails? I'm using PHPMailer.

What setting do I need to change when sending email only as plain text, it's for a domain registration form.

Comment: Mail clients don't really bother about encodings anymore. Just take the one that has the characters you need. In doubt, always use UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you would select an encoding that matches that of your web site (or, more specifically, the form you're using to fill in the E-Mail with).

UTF-8 is certainly the encoding of choice, especially if you expect international customers.

If your form encoding and desired E-Mail encoding differ, you can convert the form data using [**iconv()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

Comment: Are there restrictions on characters used in plain-text version of email's body? I posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703012/are-there-restrictions-on-characters-used-in-plain-text-version-of-emails-body  -  in case you would like to give your answer... ( I would appreciate that ! )